# How do you test functions that return Result?

Tags: testing, rust

I have a function that returns `Result<(), MyError>` where:

```
enum MyError {Error1, Error2}
```

I am currently doing the following:

```
#[test]
fn test_result_function() {
    assert_eq!((), result_function().unwrap());
}
```

This works but seems awkward. At first I was going to do:

```
assert!(result_function().is_ok());
```

but when it wasn't ok, the test result didn't give the error anywhere. How should I go about testing this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
assert_eq!(Ok(()), result_function());
```

this needs

```
#[derive(PartialEq,Debug)]
enum MyError{Error1, Error2}
```

to work and will tell you

```
`(left == right)` (left: `Ok(())`, right: `Err(Error1)`)'
```

when testing when your `result_function` returns an `Error1` when the test says it should return `Ok(())`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Still not used to traits. Here is [PartialEq](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html) if someone wants to look at it.